# C, read file and split

Tags: c, split, fopen

I have an input file (txt) with with exactly two lines, separated by a `\n`.

For example:

```
FOO
BAR
```

Now I have to put the first line (in my example FOO) in a `char **a` and the second line (BAR) in `char **b`.

I have no idea how to make this work; can you explain?

Comment: What is the separator of your split ?

Comment: What have you tried? And are you really sure you mean `char **a`, and not e.g. `char *a`?

Comment: Is this some sort of homework question? Are you supposed to put the lines into an array of `char *` - a `char **`?

Comment: @unwind OP said "read and split" so I think FOO is to be separated into many `char*`

Comment: try `fopen()`, `getline()` or `fgets()` and `strtok()` and `fclose()`.

Comment: If OP would like to answer on what's the separator maybe we could provide a correct answer, in C...

Comment: To me this looks like the task is to create a pointer to an array of pointers each pointing to one character ... - otherwise the `char **` indeed would make no sense.

Comment: sry for bad texting.
i have a given function:
long foobar(char **a, char **b)

in this function i have to split a given text file. in this text file are exactly TWO lines. the first line should be saved in **a, the seocndline in **b.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use dynamic allocation you have to allocate a vector of char using a char pointer `(char *, not char **)`:

```
#define MAX_CHAR 100
char *buffer = (char*) malloc (MAX_CHAR * sizeof(char));
```

Then you colud use [fgets](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/fgets/) function that reads characters from stream and stores them as a C string into buffer:

```
FILE * pFile;
pFile = fopen ("myfile.txt" , "r");
if (pFile == NULL) 
   perror ("Error opening file");
else {
  if(fgets (buffer, MAX_CHAR, pFile) != NULL)
    puts (buffer);
}

fclose (pFile);
```

In this way you store the first line into buffer, use two times fgets to save first and second line where you want, you can use a not-dynamic vector too.

Don't forget to:

```
free(buffer);
```

In my opinion you don't need a char**, bacause having the char *buffer with all text inside you can use [strtok](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strtok/) to split it.

Comment: This is not the question, the question is about getting each line, and _then_ splitting each line into bits, thus having a `char**`

Comment: Also this is not puts(mystring) but puts(buffer).

Comment: a char** is an array of strings, if you want to tokenize your input look at strtok() otherwise by definition a string is a sequence of chars which is what I'm reading "_then_ splitting each line into bits..."

Comment: @gliderkite yup better. But you're only reading MAX_CHARS from the file at once, so you can't use strtok() right away, you have to concatenate your buffers to have a full line.
@lukecampbell you dont _split_ a line into chars, it IS a series of chars. OP wants two `char**` so I assume he gets one line as a `char*` and then splits it and gets many `char*` arranged into an array so `char**`.

Comment: Please excuse, but a `char**` is a pointer to a pointer to a character and nothing else in the first place, anything else depends on the context where it does appear. @eregrith

Comment: @alk Yes but as a `char*` can be incremented to get the `char` next to it and thus create a "string", a `char**` can be incremented to point to the `char*` next to it and thus creating a series of pointers to `char`, or an array. `char **a` is like `char *a[]`, it can be used to store multiple `char*`, so multiple sub-strings.

Comment: @alk I could also say "a `char*` is nothing else than a pointer to a character so using it as a series depends on the context", but we all know `char*` is mainly used for it "string" purpose. Likewise a `char**` is also used a lot to have more than one `char*` and not just pointing to a pointer.

Comment: @Eregrith: I did understand perfecty what you meant, so please excuse I did not marked my comment as advocatic, but as we are somehow doing basics here, I tended to be formal. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

i don't know why there's two double pointers up there, which i think is not necessary.

to read a file from `.txt`, you need something called `FILE`. use it to open the `.txt` file, for example:
 `FILE *open = fopen("a.txt", "r");`;`*open` is the name which will be used through the code(as an opened file) while `a.txt` here means the `.txt` file you want to open and `r` is the mode, which on this case, is `read`, which means you only want to read data from the file.

after you open the file, you read the data(of course it is) with a help of looping, until the end of file. here we got the condition written as follows: `while(!feof(open))`.

you got the loop, now you have to read the data. to read data from a file, you'll need a function called `fscanf`, which will read data from the file. you use it like this: `fscanf(open,"%s\n", temp[i]);`; while `open` is the name of the file which you have opened before, `"%s\n"` means that you want to read a string until it reach `\n`, and `temp[i]` is the variable where you store the data.

now you have got the data, you don't need `FILE` anymore. just close it using `fclose(open)`.

well, i think i have explained about how to do it to you, now it's your turn to find out how to code it(it's a homework, right? it won't be a homework if you don't try it for yourself ;))

and if you still get confused about it, just try searching about it. i'm sure there're lots of reference for you to learn from.

CMIIW :)